# How to change path for contact us page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

My contact us code is coming from this file

> frontend/base/default/template/outsourceOnline/captcha/contacts.phtml

i want to **change layout** from new path 
(`outsourceOnline/captcha/contacts.phtml`) 
to old path (`default/mytheme/template/contacts/form.phtml`
)

In short i want to use default template page for contact us. i dont want use outsourceOnline extension.

Comment: Enable admin template hint  http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints .as per as magento ,if your contacts page url is YourInstaneUrl/contacts/  then cannot comes from cms page.

Comment: yes my contact page url  is www.website.com/contacts